# How to print all string values that match a common variable name?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists. The first index is an ID number, and the second is a string associated with it. An example of the first few rows is:

[['108-002 ', 'BLACK'], ['108-002 ', 'WHITE'], ['108-002 ', 'RED'], ['108-002 ', 'GREEN'], ['110-003 ', 'GREEN'], ['110-003 ', 'RED'], ['110-004 ', 'RED'], ['110-004 ', 'BLACK'], ['110-004 ', 'PURPLE']]

What I am wanting is to be able to print out something that reads like:

108-002 had BLACK, WHITE, RED, GREEN

110-003 had GREEN, RED

110-004 had RED, BLACK, PURPLE

How would you accomplish this?

I've tried multiple neseted for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` to store a list of values for each id.

```py
l = [['108-002 ', 'BLACK'], ['108-002 ', 'WHITE'], ['108-002 ', 'RED'], ['108-002 ', 'GREEN'], ['110-003 ', 'GREEN'], ['110-003 ', 'RED'], ['110-004 ', 'RED'], ['110-004 ', 'BLACK'], ['110-004 ', 'PURPLE']]
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in l:
    res[key].append(val)
print(dict(res))
```

If elements with the same id are always consecutive, `itertools.groupby` can be used.

```py
from itertools import groupby
for key, group in groupby(l, key=lambda x:x[0]):
    print(key, 'had', ', '.join(x[1] for x in group))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, either of those works really well.